# Give Group Read/Write Access to /home directory

Tags: 16.04, permissions, sftp

I have an `SFTP` server with a file directory with permissions like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root admin-accts 4096 Jun 17 03:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root        4096 Jun 17 01:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root a3466       4096 Jun 17 04:19 a3466
drwxr-xr-x  4 root a3486       4096 Jun 17 04:04 a3486
```

In the `sshd_config` file, I have set the `admin-accts` group to have `ChrootDirectory /home`.

Currently, the `admin-accts` group can read `/home/a3466` but cannot write to it.  The `a3466` group can read and write to `/home/a3466`.

How can I set the permissions so that `admin-accts` group can read and write to `/home/a3466` and the `a3466` group can only read `/home/a3466`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the directory permissions by doing `chmod 777 /directory` this will allow everyone in every group and all other people to read, write, and execute.

Comment: I had tried that in the past, but it then prevented users from logging in saying `bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/a3466"`

Comment: Could you please perform stat --format "%a" /directory . And post the output.

Comment: Ok sure, it just output 755. I am also running this on an Amazon EC2 instance if that helps.

Comment: Hmm. I think you should try my answer I posted and see if that does anything. Then post the output.

Comment: I got it working with what you said. But what I was trying was doing chmod 777 /home when I needed to do it on /home/a3486.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm so glad I could help!!! @MikeDeluca